# Why wont Mathematica plot my two functions on the same graph?

Tags: plotting, functions

So I have defined two functions

```
s[p_] = -600 + 50 p
d[p_] = 1200 - 25 p
```

and I want to graph both of them on the same chart using the

```
Plot[{50 p - 600, -25 p + 1200}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotLegends → {"Function 1", "Function 2"}]
```

However, when I evaluate the cells, I get and error saying

> Plot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of PlotLegends->{Function
>   1,Function 2}) beyond position 2 in Plot[{50 p-600,-4
>   p+1200},{p,-10,10},PlotLegends->{Function 1,Function 2}]. An option
>   must be a rule or a list of rules.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: PlotLegends is obsolete. If you erase this part your function will be drawn

Comment: The problem seems to be with the arrow character (`→`).  Try deleting it and replacing it with `->`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[{50 p - 600, -25 p + 1200}, {p, -10, 10}, 
PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", Below]]
```

or

```
Plot[{50 p - 600, -25 p + 1200}, {p, -10, 10}, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[{"f1", "g1"}, Below]]
```

Comment: `Placed` is not necessary; try `Plot[{50 p-600,-25 p+1200},{x,-10,10},PlotLegends->{"Function 1","Function 2"}]` (the original, but without the `→` character).